# how to add maven in project level gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I want to use own library but need to add maven in project level gradle my latest project level gradle only cosists of below lines so not able to add maven and could not able to get the library.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
}
```

This above code is present in project level gradle.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. Can you please rephrase / clarify?

Comment: I want to add the google services plugin so it helps me to integrate the firebase to my android app with latest gradle changes.